# How to create Abstract Syntax Tree nodes when the operator and operands are not in the same production?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

So in all cases of AST examples, there are productions of the following kind:

```
    expr -> expr "+" expr;
    expr -> expr "-" expr;

And in this case it's easy to create a new node like this:

    expr: expr "+" expr {newNode("+",$1,$3);}
    ;
```

Now my grammar has the following implementation:

```
    assignment:IDENTIFIER '=' expression ';' 
    ;
    expression:term expression_1
    ;
    expression_1: '+' term expression_1 |
    '-' term expression_1 |
    ;
    term: factor term_1 
    ;
    term_1: '*' factor term_1 |
    '/' factor term_1 |
    ;
    factor: IDENTIFIER |
    '(' expression ')' | 
    NUM | FNUM | STRING
    ;
```

Here, while making a new node, how do I take the first operand(which is in a previous production), and feed that into a newNode function which will have the operator and the second operand(both of these are together in a different production)?

Comment: "Now my grammar has the following implementation in yacc" Why? It looks like you've made your grammar LL(1), but Bison is not an LL(1) parser generator, so there's no reason to do that.

Comment: I have no choice but to stick with the grammar. I have to build an AST from it but since both the operands and the operator are not being found in the same production, idk how to tackle that.

Comment: I'm really stuck over here, only if this thing is figured out for me, my AST is done.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the circumstances here? @sepp2k’s comment about your choice of grammar is an important one, and the easiest way to solve this might be to change the grammar to more naturally match what the tools do.

Comment: I have to create an AST for any file that is fed to the compiler. I have to take care of expressions, if-else and while constructs. The grammar has been given to me, I can't change it. It's been used in three other fully functioning programs, so I'm expected to continue with the same.

Comment: The real problem is that the (right-recursive) grammar does not model the actual parse tree, unless your language considers arithmetic operators to be right associative, which would be extremely idiosyncratic. Passing multiple values up through a reduction action only requires a struct with two fields.